# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs-directive, asp.net-core-mvc

Just new to angularjs and have been finding a way to get an app running. Very simple and straight forward:

Angular controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myQuotesApp')
        .controller('QuotesController', QuotesController);

    QuotesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'Quotes']; 

    function QuotesController($scope, Quotes) {
        $scope.quotes = Quotes.query();
    }
})();
```

This is the service class of angularjs

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var QuotesService = angular.module('QuotesService', '[ngResource]');
    QuotesService.factory('Quotes', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/quotes/', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray:true }
        });
    }]);
})();
```

THis is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myQuotesApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My Quotes App</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="QuotesController">
        <H2>List of Quotes</H2>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="quote in quotes">
                <p> "{{quote.Content}}" - {{quote.Author}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The server side model:

```
public class Quote
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

The server side controller:

```
public IEnumerable<Quote> Get()
        {
            return new List<Quote> {
                new Quote { Id=1, Author="James John",       Comment="This guy is good to work with."},
                new Quote { Id=2, Author="Larry Page",       Comment="This is one of the best guys in the IT world"},
                new Quote { Id=3, Author="Goodwill Adebayo", Comment="It is always good to work with God." }
            };
        }
```

Whenever I run the app it displays a blank page. I checked the browser console and I got this error:

```
angular.js:4640Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myQuotesApp&p1=Erro…http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A60261%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A390)
jquery-1.9.0.js:1 '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
```

Comment: Have you injected the modules properly? Looks like you missed out on injecting some module.

Comment: Please can you kindly point me to the missing link? Appreciate.

Comment: kehinde, you're long enough on SO that you should know, not to force tags into the question title: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging. Also don't use asp.net-mvc6, there is no MVC6. It's called ASP.NET Core MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing few pieces. You'll need to create **myQuotesApp** module first before using it.

Working Example at Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/l3UmoDjjGhaQq0JNjtsF.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
      .module('myQuotesApp', ['ngResource']) // <----
      .controller('QuotesController', QuotesController);

    QuotesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'QuotesService']; 

    function QuotesController($scope, QuotesService) {
        $scope.quotes = QuotesService.query();
    }

    angular
      .module('myQuotesApp')
      .factory('QuotesService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        var query = function() {
          return [{Content: "One", Author: "John"}, 
            {Content: "Two", Author: "Eric"}]
        }
        return {
          query: query 
        }
    }]);
})();
```

### How to pull data from Web API

You just need to update QuotesService to use $resource.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myQuotesApp', ['ngResource'])
        .controller('QuotesController', QuotesController);

    QuotesController.$inject = ['$scope', 'QuotesService'];

    function QuotesController($scope, QuotesService) {
        $scope.quotes = QuotesService.query();
        console.log($scope.quotes);
    }

    angular
        .module('myQuotesApp')
        .factory('QuotesService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/quotes/', {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
            });
        }]);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I appreciate your support. I have serverside mode and controller that I want to be pulling from, how do I implement this?

Comment: Words can't well express how well I appreciate your spport. Worked perfectly!